# How to Populate JSON when Referencing a Node Module

Tags: json, node.js, function

I'm trying to pass variables into a function that is from a Node module, but am getting errors in the response object.  Is this possible?  Do I need to parse the JSON?

I tried the following:

app.js

```
var customer = require('./customer');
customer.createCustomer({
  given_name: "first name",
  family_name: "last name",
  email_address: "abc@email.com"
});
```

customer.js

```
const unirest = require('unirest'),
  access_token = 'sq0atp-1234',
  domain = 'https://connect.squareup.com/v2/';

module.exports = {

  createCustomer: function(given_name, family_name, email_address) {
    unirest.post(domain + 'customers')
      .headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
      })
      .send({
        "given_name": given_name,
        "family_name": family_name,
        "email_address": email_address
      })
      .end(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
  }
}
```

The createCustomer function works when it's run directly using strings.

Comment: check the method signature. the method is expecting each each response property to be a function argument and you are passing a single object as argument. follow the function contract and all will be fine. please delete the question before is down voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function must contain object literal syntax, e.g.

```
createCustomer: function({given_name, family_name, email_address}){...}
```

instead of

```
createCustomer: function(given_name, family_name, email_address){...}
```